# Logic Hook: Cycling through an array in SugarCRM

Tags: php, arrays, sugarcrm

We're using SugarCRM to process leads that come in for clients, but would like to cycle through the clients so that the leads are distributed evenly. I suspect it will be just cycling through an array for each new lead that comes in, so I wanted to know how you could cycle through an array using PHP, so that each load prints a new value. I saw this similar question ([PHP Cycle through array. Move the first element to the last](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19272474/2788655)), but wasn't sure how to repeat it after it had resolved once.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Normally to "cycle through an array" one would use `each` or `foreach`, but I suspect the leads come in at different times, and so you would therefore need to record whose turn it is next in a database. Perhaps maintain a list of leads that each client has received, so you can work out who has received the least.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is commonly called `Round Robin` so you might want to look into that as well